# nested json by underscore.js

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

i have found these related posts but not able to solve my issue

[Underscore, Nested Group By and Generate a JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665676/underscore-nested-group-by-and-generate-a-json)

[Grouping a nested array with underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221432/grouping-a-nested-array-with-underscore-js)

I want to group like following :

[image]

like  StartDate ---> FunctionID--> STartTime

this is my query result

[image]

and json result is like following :

```
[{"Act_Qty":0,"FunctionID":268,"ResDesc":"Anniversary Party","StartTime_EndTime":"04:00:00 AM - 04:30:00 AM"},
[{"Act_Qty":0,"FunctionID":268,"ResDesc":"Anniversary Party","StartTime_EndTime":"04:00:00 AM - 04:30:00 AM"}]
```

for nested json grouping I Tried following different queries :

```
var result = _.chain(jsonData)
.groupBy('StartDate')
.mapObject( StartDate => _.groupBy(StartDate, 'FunctionID'))
.value();


var result = _.chain(jsonData)
.groupBy('FunctionID')
.mapObject( FunctionID => _.groupBy(FunctionID,'StartDate' ))
.value();
```

but this is giving me results like

[image]

and

[image]

like same functions in inner group ,But i want different functions in inner group

please suggest

Comment: plz provide some input sample and expected output format.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: *"...and json result is like following..."* That isn't JSON.

Comment: @NeerajVerma - *"I already did everything"* No, [Aagam's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473294/nested-json-by-underscore-js#comment91888316_52473294) requested an input sample and expected output format. There's no "input sample" in the question that I can see. And a picture of table isn't "output format" (it's a *rendering* of the output format). If you want people to help you, you need to provide them with clear, complete information.

Comment: @NeerajVerma can you plz provide json itself as It is hard to get data from screenshot.

Comment: OK ,i am adding , i have changed input , now converting output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can nested group data.

```js
data = [{
  "StartDate": "2018-09-11",
  "FunctionID": "276",
  "StartTime_EndTime": "08:00:00 AM - 11:00:00 AM",
  "ResDesc": "Breakfast",
  "functionRoom": "Living Room",
  "Gurenteed": "13",
  "Expr": "12",
  "Act_Qty": "13",
  "Charge": "19",
  "Item": "Tea Sandwitches and Salads"
}, {
  "StartDate": "2018-09-11",
  "FunctionID": "276",
  "StartTime_EndTime": "08:00:00 AM - 11:00:00 AM",
  "ResDesc": "Breakfast",
  "functionRoom": "Living Room",
  "Gurenteed": "13",
  "Expr": "12",
  "Act_Qty": "13",
  "Charge": "18",
  "Item": "Pasta Station"
}, {
  "StartDate": "2018-09-12",
  "FunctionID": "295",
  "StartTime_EndTime": "07:00:00 AM - 07:30:00 AM",
  "ResDesc": "Breakfast",
  "functionRoom": "Living Room",
  "Gurenteed": "13",
  "Expr": "12",
  "Act_Qty": "13",
  "Charge": "1",
  "Item": "Tea Sandwitches and Salads"
}, {
  "StartDate": "2018-09-12",
  "FunctionID": "295",
  "StartTime_EndTime": "07:00:00 AM - 07:30:00 AM",
  "ResDesc": "Breakfast",
  "functionRoom": "Living Room",
  "Gurenteed": "26",
  "Expr": "18",
  "Act_Qty": "19",
  "Charge": "9",
  "Item": "Coffee"
}, {
  "StartDate": "2018-09-13",
  "FunctionID": "298",
  "StartTime_EndTime": "09:00:00 AM - 11:00:00 AM",
  "ResDesc": "Breakfast",
  "functionRoom": "Living Room",
  "Gurenteed": "13",
  "Expr": "12",
  "Act_Qty": "13",
  "Charge": "19",
  "Item": "Tea Sandwitches and Salads"
}, {
  "StartDate": "2018-09-13",
  "FunctionID": "298",
  "StartTime_EndTime": "07:00:00 AM - 11:00:00 AM",
  "ResDesc": "Breakfast",
  "functionRoom": "Living Room",
  "Gurenteed": "13",
  "Expr": "12",
  "Act_Qty": "13",
  "Charge": "18",
  "Item": "Pasta Station"
}, {
  "StartDate": "2018-09-15",
  "FunctionID": "299",
  "StartTime_EndTime": "06:00:00 AM - 07:30:00 AM",
  "ResDesc": "Breakfast",
  "functionRoom": "Living Room",
  "Gurenteed": "13",
  "Expr": "12",
  "Act_Qty": "13",
  "Charge": "1",
  "Item": "Tea Sandwitches and Salads"
}, {
  "StartDate": "2018-09-16",
  "FunctionID": "299",
  "StartTime_EndTime": "06:30:00 AM - 07:30:00 AM",
  "ResDesc": "Breakfast",
  "functionRoom": "Living Room",
  "Gurenteed": "26",
  "Expr": "18",
  "Act_Qty": "19",
  "Charge": "9",
  "Item": "Coffee"
}];

var byStartDate = _.groupBy(data, 'StartDate');
_.each(byStartDate, (d, i) => {
  byStartDate[i] = _.groupBy(d, 'FunctionID');
  _.each(byStartDate[i], (d1, i1) => {
    byStartDate[i][i1] = _.groupBy(d1, d2 => {
      return d2["StartTime_EndTime"].split("-")[0].trim();
    });
  });
});

console.log(byStartDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

let me know if any concern.